# flex sdk actionscript 3 compile

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

can the flex sdk compile actionscript files that imports flash controls ? I have

```
import fl.controls.TextArea;
```

as a import statement and it says Definition fl.controls:TextArea could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

The flex is using it's own TextArea component

```
mx.components.TextArea
```

or

```
spark.components.TextArea
```

depending on Flex SDK version you are using.